# Host Angular 7 in Azure web app URL rewrite problem

Tags: angular, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have created a webapp in Azure to host my Angular 7 site. However I have a problem with the background image not being shown on the site.

It works fine locally.

In the console I get the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The background image is located in /assets/images/
If I try to go directly to the image path I get this error:
[image]

I need help to find out why the background doesn't show and what I have done wrong

Comment: where did you put this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. 
When the angular app was build with

```
ng build --prod
```

Two web.config files where deployed.
One in the root folder and one in the assets folder.

I found that this was done because the angular.json file had this configuration in it.

The solution was to remove the marked line form the configuration:

```
    "assets": [
      "src/assets",
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/web.config" <---- Removed this line
    ],
```

Hope this can help someone.