# Not able to download the json data in https server, same works fine in local

Tags: json, angular, angular-services, angular8

I am using static data from "assets" folder, by importing like this:

`import programmeManagment from './../../../assets/mock-json/programme-management.json';`

and using in service like:

`return of(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(programmeManagment)));`

it works fine in local host. when i move the code to server, it shows the error as:

`https:xxx.azurewebsites.net/assets/mock-json/programme-management.json`
`404 Not Found`  response shows as:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

how to come up with this?

Comment: what happens when you paste `https:xxx.azurewebsites.net/assets/mock-json/programme-management.json` in browser did it download or open the file?

Comment: @jitender : `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: this may help http://microdesigncentre.com/hosting-angular-app-on-windows-azure-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed/

Comment: @3gwebtrain Its looks like this `./../../../` part may be going into the wrong directory to seach file

Comment: @Prashant but it works fine with local host right?

Comment: Yes, agreed! what is your baseurl while build/publish? or have you written any URL Rewrite rules?

Comment: One more SO post related to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054707/angular-2-azure-deploy-refresh-error-the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been

Comment: @Prashant:@base url in `index.html` -? `<base href="/">`

Comment: @3gwebtrain Okay and what about second question? about Url rewrite role on server?

Comment: I don't write any url rewrite rules, it will be in tsconfig file right? there is nothing. config base url : `"baseUrl": "./",`

Comment: @3gwebtrain Nope it has to be written on IIS/Azure server [check this or search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940859/host-angular-7-in-azure-web-app-url-rewrite-problem) + [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786139/host-angular2-app-with-routing-in-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested by prashath, got issue fixed. sharing for others to use it.
taken the answer from here: [Host Angular 7 in Azure web app URL rewrite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940859/host-angular-7-in-azure-web-app-url-rewrite-problem)

```
 "assets": [
      "src/assets",
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/web.config" <---- Removed this line
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
this.http.get('./../../../assets/mock-json/programme-management.json').subscribe( res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: I tried already it was fails. what I updated with question is new try.

Answer (score 0):

Please check file programme-management.json is available in your hosted location.

If not there try changing special character from the file name.

instead of,

programme-management.json.

use this,

programmemanagement.json